# notifyWith isn't working with $.when

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I am learning how to use jQuery's [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), and I noticed an issue with using [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) along with [`.notifyWith`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.notifyWith/).

I made an example without using `$.when`, and `.notifyWith` works perfectly

```
function a() {
    var d = new $.Deferred,
        $A = $('#A'),
        $P = $('#P').progressbar();

    setTimeout(function() {
        $A.css('background-color', 'blue');
        d.notifyWith($P, [.5]);
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $A.text('test');
        d.notifyWith($P, [1]);
        d.resolveWith($P, ['done']);
    }, 4000);

    return d.promise();
}
$('#G').click(function() {
    a().progress(function(x) {
        this.progressbar({
            value: x * 100
        });
    }).done(function(x) {
        alert(x)
    });
});​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/NTICompass/3DDSa/3/

Inside [`.progress`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.progress/), `this` is set to `$P`, so the progressbar moves correctly.

I wanted to split the 2 `setTimeout` actions into separate functions, so I did that and used `$.when` to combine the promises into one:

```
(function() {
    var $P = $('#P').progressbar();
    window.a = function() {
        var d = new $.Deferred,
            $A = $('#A');

        setTimeout(function() {
            $A.css('background-color', 'blue');
            d.notifyWith($P, [.5]);
            d.resolve('a()');
        }, 2000);

        return d.promise();
    }

    window.b = function() {
        var d = new $.Deferred,
            $A = $('#A');

        setTimeout(function() {
            $A.text('test');
            d.notifyWith($P, [.5]);
            d.resolve('b()');
        }, 4000);

        return d.promise();
    }
}())

$('#G').click(function() {
    $.when(a(), b()).progress(function(x, y) {
        this.progressbar({
            value: ((x || 0) + (y || 0)) * 100
        });
    }).done(function(x, y) {
        alert(x + ' ' + y)
    });
});​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/NTICompass/3DDSa/16/

For some reason `this` inside of `.progress` is *not* `$P`.  Instead it's the deferred object (or the promise object, I'm not really sure).  Why isn't `this` equal to `$P`?

Comment: line 1336 of 1.7.2 http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js would be where it passes the promise as the context, for reference.

Comment: @KevinB: So, might this be a bug in (the almighty) jQuery?

Comment: Docs do say: `deferred.notifyWith( context [, args] )` "Context passed to the progressCallbacks as the `this` object." Might be a bug?

Comment: The problem still happens with jQuery 1.8.0. http://jsfiddle.net/NTICompass/3DDSa/17/

Comment: **To the jQuery bug tracker!**  Away!

Comment: @IanBishop: Let's see what jQuery thinks: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12253

Comment: For the record, it works correctly without `$.when` - http://jsfiddle.net/3DDSa/19/

Comment: @IanBishop: Yeah, seems `$.when` is breaking the context of `notifyWith`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in jQuery 1.8.0 where `this` is actually an array of contexts.

```
$('#G').click(function() {
    var index = 0;
    $.when(a(), b()).progress(function(x, y) {
        this[index++].progressbar({
            value: ((x || 0) + (y || 0)) * 100
        });
    }).done(function(x, y) {
        alert(x + ' ' + y)
    });
});​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3D4wq/1/ (Thanks to [jaubourg](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12253#comment:2) from the jQuery bug tracker)

Note: That inside `.progress` (and `.done`), `arguments.length` will always be the number of elements passed to `$.when`, so `this[arguments.length-1]` won't (always) work.

The 1st time `.progress` is called `arguments` is `[.5, undefined]`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a reason for it to be written the way it is, but simply changing `promise` on line 1336 to `this` does make your code run as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/3DDSa/18/

```
$.when = function(firstParam) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0),
        i = 0,
        length = args.length,
        pValues = new Array(length),
        count = length,
        pCount = length,
        deferred = length <= 1 && firstParam && jQuery.isFunction(firstParam.promise) ? firstParam : jQuery.Deferred(),
        promise = deferred.promise();

    function resolveFunc(i) {
        return function(value) {
            args[i] = arguments.length > 1 ? [].slice.call(arguments, 0) : value;
            if (!(--count)) {
                deferred.resolveWith(deferred, args);
            }
        };
    }

    function progressFunc(i) {
        return function(value) {
            pValues[i] = arguments.length > 1 ? [].slice.call(arguments, 0) : value;
            deferred.notifyWith(this, pValues); // this is line 1336
        };
    }
    if (length > 1) {
        for (; i < length; i++) {
            if (args[i] && args[i].promise && jQuery.isFunction(args[i].promise)) {
                args[i].promise().then(resolveFunc(i), deferred.reject, progressFunc(i));
            } else {
                --count;
            }
        }
        if (!count) {
            deferred.resolveWith(deferred, args);
        }
    } else if (deferred !== firstParam) {
        deferred.resolveWith(deferred, length ? [firstParam] : []);
    }
    return promise;
};​
```

May be worth adding to the ticket.

Comment: Would you like to add this as a comment to the [ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12253), or should I?

Comment: Seems like `resolveWith` would have the same issue `deferred.resolveWith(deferred, args);` :-P